# MySQL server connection in react native

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native

my question is I having a NAS and I already set up the MySQL inside the NAS and also my react native app also work perfectly with the connection but the problem is when my device is not connected to the wifi or using mobile data, it cannot fetch the api that I have created in the NAS folder, and the connection between the MySQL server and device will be corrupted. So the problem from me now is, it is possible to connect or send data into the Mysql server when the device is using mobile data